# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I have checked many answers on StackOverflow with the same title, but can't seem to find my mistake. I am following a tutorial on Udemy.

I'm calling a function in the render method of AlbumList Component. The function iterates over an array of albums and passes each to an AlbumDetail Component and returns the components as a list.

### AlbumList Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import View from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';

class AlbumList extends Component {
  state = {
    albums: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
  }

  renderAlbums() {
    return this.state.albums.map(album =>
      <AlbumDetail key={album.title} album={album} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderAlbums()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

### AlbumDetail Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
  console.log('Inside AlbumDetail');
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AlbumDetail;
```

### Edit

I have removed the curly bracket '{}' from the AlbumDetail import in the AlbumList Component. Still makes no difference

### Error

[Error Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2yKl.png)

### Console Log (AlbumDetail Component)

[console.log returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZXXU.png)

Comment: im sorry, what's your problem and error ? you can explain it please :)

Comment: I have added the error stack image to the question. I don't understand it properly, I have just started learning React, but I think maybe I am passing the prop to the child component incorrectly ? Although this is how the tutorial I'm following has done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m fairly certain that `import { AlbumDetail } ...` was the cause of the error. It should be `import AlbumDetail ...` as it’s a default import.

Also, you have a typo in your AlbumDetail component’s return. You spelled album wrong.

**Edit**

There is another error with `import View from ‘react-native’`. It should be `import { View } from ‘react-native’` in AlbumList component.

Comment: Nope... corrected both mistakes. Still doesn't work. I have added the Error Stack Image to the question. If that helps. Thanks

Comment: Try console.log(AlbumDetail) after your import and check what is actually getting imported. Also, it might be helpful to update your snippets with the latest code you have right now

Comment: It returns js function which returns the createElement function to render the element. Added the snapshot of the console.log to the question

Comment: Thank you very much. I up-voted your answer but I dont have enough score or something, so my upvote doesn't count .. I'm sorry :P... 

Although can you please explain this? I am specifically removing brackets in import statements where there is only one import. I thought this practice was required.

Comment: Check https://github.com/DrkSephy/es6-cheatsheet#modules for details but long story short, there are two types of import/export - default export and named export. There’s only one default export per module, and there can be many named export per module. import Blah from ‘some module’ means you are importing the default export from that module and named it blah. Import { Blah } from ‘some module’ means you are importing a named export of the module, named Blah.

Comment: And you can accept this answer as the correct one if you can’t vote :)

Comment: Done and Thank you

Comment: Great! Happy to help